# Is the cordova-plugin-x-toast available in browser?

Tags: cordova, npm, cross-browser, cordova-plugins, toast

I am trying to use the cordova-plugin-x-toast to use toast in my cordova application on browser, but when i try to make it show up an alert says: *toast error: Missing Command Error*. The documentation says that it works for iOS, Android and WP8, but it also says *It's great for showing a non intrusive native notification which is guaranteed always in the viewport of the browser*, doesn't it means that it showld works in browser too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the [src folder of the plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin/tree/master/src), there is no browser platform for this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I created a sample cordova project using this plugin and tested in it browser. It does not work in browser as 'CommandProxyMap' itself is not populated. The same works fine in Android. So I assume the plugin documentation means the view port of the android browser not browser platform.